# SQL Statement not exists in

Tags: sql

I want to select entries from first table that have no entries in second table

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    first.clientid
FROM
    table1 AS first,
    table2 AS second
WHERE
    first.clientid NOT IN second.clientid
```

but i have realize problem

any tips?

Comment: That's wrong syntax. Have you tried anything else?

Comment: For future requests: Please always tell us what goes wrong. Here: that you get a syntax error. State the exact error message. Also tell us what database system you use. Don't let us guess things you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to do that:

```
SELECT first.clientid 
FROM table1 AS first
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM table2 AS second WHERE first.clientid = second.clientid)
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrong Syntax.

Either use IN:

```
SELECT clientid FROM table1
WHERE clientid NOT IN (SELECT clientid FROM table2);
```

Or use EXISTS:

```
SELECT clientid FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 where table2.clientid = table1.clientid);
```

Or use MINUS (not avaliable in every DBMS):

```
SELECT clientid FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT clientid FROM table2;
```